# "I've got so much work" - does this phrase need to be finished by "to do"?

Tags: infinitives

I'm always writing down that phrase without that infinitive part "to do". In that case, I mean that I have to do all the work, but it's only mine interpretation and it seems to be a likely misconception because whenever I was searching for that phrase it ended with that infinitive part ("to do").

Comment: No, it is just an option. It's  your choice whether you add to do or not. I am sure the same is true in whatever your native language is, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing grammatically wrong with *I've got so much work*, but *I've got so much work to do* has a more precise meaning. It means you have a lot of work, all of which is unfinished, and all of which you must do yourself. It also implies that although it's a lot of work, it is a specific set of work that you *can* eventually finish.

Without the *to do* you might have a lot of work, at least some of which you plan to assign to others. As in the following:

> I've got so much work for you.

It could also mean that you have a neverending, steady supply of work and that as soon as you finish one task, another task takes its place. As in the following:

> I've got so much work that I have to work 70 hours per week.

So, usually, you would need more context to make your meaning completely clear, while *I've got so much work to do* is already entirely clear.